# How to make in WordPress admin panel sortable column for the custom field, that count the number of page impressions?

Tags: custom-post-types, php, wp-admin, sort

Good day!
I try to make display post counter for WordPress.

**Output count of views**

```
function getPostViews($postID){
$count_key = 'post_views_count';
$count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
if($count==''){
    delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
    add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
    return "0";    }
return $count.'';}
```

**register view**

```
function setPostViews($postID) {
$count_key = 'post_views_count';
$count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
if($count==''){
    $count = 0;
    delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
    add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
}else{
    $count++;
    update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);    }}
```

**output count of views in the admin panel**

```
add_filter('manage_pages_columns', 'posts_column_views');
add_action('manage_pages_custom_column', 'posts_custom_column_views',10,2);
add_filter('manage_posts_columns', 'posts_column_views');
add_action('manage_posts_custom_column', 'posts_custom_column_views',10,2);
function posts_column_views($defaults){
    $defaults['post_views'] = __('Views');
    return $defaults;}
function posts_custom_column_views($column_name, $id){
    if($column_name === 'post_views'){
        echo getPostViews(get_the_ID());    }}
```

*Everything works!!!*

**Adds the ability to sort column**

```
add_filter('manage_edit-post_sortable_columns', 'add_views_sortable_column');
add_filter('manage_edit-page_sortable_columns', 'add_views_sortable_column');
add_filter('manage_edit-slides_sortable_columns', 'add_views_sortable_column');
add_filter('manage_edit-hp_highlights_sortable_columns', 'add_views_sortable_column');
add_filter('manage_edit-portfolio_sortable_columns', 'add_views_sortable_column');
add_filter('manage_edit-staff_sortable_columns', 'add_views_sortable_column');
add_filter('manage_edit-services_sortable_columns', 'add_views_sortable_column');
add_filter('manage_edit-testimonials_sortable_columns', 'add_views_sortable_column');
add_filter('manage_edit-faqs_sortable_columns', 'add_views_sortable_column');
function add_views_sortable_column($sortable_columns){
  $sortable_columns['post_views'] = 'views_views';
  return $sortable_columns;}
```

It becomes possible to sort by column "**Views**", by pressing the string has the form: */wp-admin/edit.php?orderby=views_views&order=desc* But in fact sorting is not on the field "**Views**", it is on the field "**Date**".

**Change the query for sorting columns show WordPress, that need sorting by random fields whose values are numbers**
(Method 1)

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'add_column_views_request');
function add_column_views_request( $object ){
  if( $object->get('orderby') != 'views_views' )
    return;
  $object->set('meta_key', 'post_views');
  $object->set('orderby', 'meta_value_num');}
```

(Method 2)

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_column_views_request', 1 );
function add_column_views_request( $query ) {
  if ( $query->is_main_query() && ( $orderby = $query->get( 'orderby' ) ) ) {
    switch( $orderby ) {
        case 'views_views':
            $query->set( 'meta_key', 'post_views' );
            $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );
        break;}}}
```

(Method 3)

```
add_filter('request', 'add_column_views_request');
function add_column_views_request( $vars ) {
    if ( 'views_views' == $vars['orderby'] ){
    $vars['meta_key'] = 'post_views';
    $vars['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';}
    return $vars;}
```

Sort simply return no results: "**No entries found**."
Tell me how to fix the code, please.

Help me with this problem?
*Thank you for your response.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just should make 
**Method 1**

```
 $object->set('meta_key', 'post_views_count');
```

**Method 2**

```
 $query->set( 'meta_key', 'post_views_count' );
```

**Method 3**

```
 $vars['meta_key'] = 'post_views_count';
```